# Get Access token genertaed from JSON in SpringBoot Application

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/check", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<Product> createProducts() throws JsonProcessingException {
      
       String reqUrl = "http://localhost:8080/home";
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
       headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
       Map<String, String> bodyParamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    bodyParamMap.put("grant_type", "K1");
    bodyParamMap.put("client_id", "K2");
    bodyParamMap.put("client_secret", "sjxjkdcnjkk");
    
    String reqBodyData = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bodyParamMap);
    HttpEntity<String> requestEnty = new  HttpEntity<>(reqBodyData, headers);
    ResponseEntity<Product> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(reqUrl, requestEnty, Product.class);
    return result;
}
```

I am geeting a JSON response form `result` which have access_token which I want to get.
I tried using JSONObject but it is not working. How Can I fetch the value of **access_token**

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(result.toString());
 String m = jsonObject.get("access_token").toString();
```

I tried using this but it is showing compile time error

My output is accepted as

```
{"access_token":"ghdjhdjhhh","expires_in":2300}
```

I want to fetch this access_token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use postForEntity your Product.class is suppose to represent your result (responseType), so if your converters are well defined(normally the spring boot default ones are sufficient for json) with your class Product looking like this

```
public class Product {


    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken;

    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private Long expiresIn;

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public Long getExpiresIn() {
        return expiresIn;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public void setExpiresIn(Long expiresIn) {
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
    }

}
```

then you can get your result like this

```
ResponseEntity<Product> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(reqUrl, requestEnty, Product.class);
Product product = result.getBody();
String token  = product.getAccessToken()
```

Comment: I have defined this in a same format but how do I fetch the value

Comment: i think there is a problem in your design, the name Product is not adapted to the content of the class, the content seems to be a JwtDto or something like that

Comment: by doing result.getBody().getAccessToken() you get the token

Comment: result.getBody() represent the embeded product in the ResponseEntity so you can do Product p = result.getBody()

Comment: can guide  me to pass this token for further authentication